# Integrals with limits

Tags: calculus, integration

I am trying to do:

$$\int_0^1 x\sin(180x^2)\, dx$$

I use substitution:
Let $ u = 180x^2 $ and $ \tfrac{du}{dx}=360x $
$$  \implies du =360x \,dx $$
$$  \implies \frac{1}{360} \, du = dx $$

so we get

$$ = 360\int_0^1 x\sin(u) \,du$$
$$\left[-\frac{1}{360}\cos(180x^2)+C\right]_0^1$$

$[-\tfrac{1}{360}\cos(180(1)^2)] \, - $ 
$[-\tfrac{1}{360}\cos(180(0)^2)] \, $ 
$$$$
$= \tfrac{1}{360} - \tfrac{1}{360} = 0$

However the answer on this site is different
http://www.integral-calculator.com/#expr=xsin%28180x%5E2%29&lbound=0&ubound=1

I dont understand how they came up with
$= \tfrac{1}{360} - \tfrac{\cos(180)}{360} = 0$
in the indefinite integral box, how did they get cos(180)?!

Comment: Is the argument in degrees or radians?

Comment: well the question was in radians but I put it into degress. Why does it matter here?

Comment: How did you go from $du=360x dx$ to $360 du=dx$?

Comment: Cause all infinitesimal calculus for trigonometric functions is constructed in radians. In particular the derivation formulaes.

Comment: @randomgirl sorry mistake in typing

Comment: Wait, was your original problem $\int_{0}^{1}x\sin(\pi x^2)\,dx$? If so, you'll get a different answer by evaluating $\int_{0}^{1}x\sin(180 x^2)\,dx$ even if you don't make the mistake of going from $du = 360x\,dx$ to $\dfrac{1}{360}du = dx$.

Comment: @JimmyK4542 yes it was

Comment: The value of the anti-derivative at $ \ x \ = \ 1 \ $ is  $ - \frac{\cos 180}{360} \ $ and the value at  $ \ x \ = \ 0 \ $ is  $ - \frac{\cos 0}{360} \ = \  - \frac{1}{360} \ $ .  So the definite integral will give $$ - \frac{\cos 180}{360} \ - \ \left( - \frac{1}{360} \right) \  =  \ - \frac{\cos 180}{360} \ + \  \frac{1}{360}     \ \ .  $$  The calculator did exactly what you asked of it (with 180 being in units of _radians_ ).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You made a mistake going from $du = 360x\,dx$ to $\dfrac{1}{360}du = dx$.

You should have gotten $\dfrac{1}{360}du = x\,dx$. Then, performing the substitution gives you

$\displaystyle\int_{0}^{1}x\sin(180x^2)\,dx = \int_{0}^{180}\dfrac{1}{360}\sin u\,du = \left[-\dfrac{1}{360}\cos u\right]_{0}^{180}$

$= -\dfrac{1}{360}\cos(180)+\dfrac{1}{360}\cos(0) = \dfrac{1}{360} - \dfrac{1}{360}\cos(180)$.

Note that by saying that the antiderivative of $\sin u$ is $-\cos u$, you are assuming the argument is in radians not degrees. The online calculator you are using also assumed the argument was in radians. Hence, $\cos(180) \neq -1$.

If your original problem was $\displaystyle\int_{0}^{1}x\sin(\pi x^2)\,dx$ and not $\displaystyle\int_{0}^{1}x\sin(180 x^2)\,dx$, then it would probably be less confusing if you left the argument in radians. The overall method will be the same.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to answer in terms of radians because that is what the OP said that the problem was in. Note that a valid solution can be found using degrees, one must just be weary. $360$ without a unit often means $360 \mathrm{rad} \neq 360^{\circ}$.

Note that $2 \pi =360^{\circ}$ and $\pi =180^{\circ}.$

For $\int x\sin(\pi x^2)\, dx$ let $u=\pi x^2$ and $du=2 \pi x$. Thus, we have $$\frac{1}{2 \pi} \int 2 \pi x\sin(\pi x^2)\, dx= \frac{1}{2 \pi} \int \sin(u)\, du= \frac{-1}{2\pi} \cos u = \frac{-1}{2\pi} \cos(\pi x^2).$$

To calculate the bounds: $$\int_0^1 x\sin(\pi x^2)\, dx= \frac{-1}{2\pi} \cos(\pi x^2)]_0^1=\frac{-1}{2 \pi} \cos(\pi(1)^2)-(\frac{-1}{2\pi} \cos(\pi(0)^2)= \frac{-1}{2 \pi}(-1-(1))=\frac{1}{\pi}$$

Overall, it seems that your problem is the difference between radians and degrees. I would strongly recommend doing all trigonometry based calculus in radians, as they are natural units to do computations in. Degrees based measurements can be extremely messy and cumbersome, because one must keep in mind that $\cos (360) \neq \cos (2\pi) = \cos {360^{\circ}}.$